# Change the startup error page in ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, startup

Is there a way to change the error page that is shown when an ASP.NET Core web app ***fails on startup***?

The error page says: "An error occurred while starting the application."
And the title says: "Internal Server Error"

[image]

I don't want this page to be seen by users. I would like to show a more user friendly page.

**Update:**
The ASP.NET Core documentation has some information on handling startup errors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1#startup-exception-handling), but nothing about showing a custom startup error page.